# Tor Browser not launching on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, tor-browser

I update to Ubuntu 22.04 and Tor Browser is not working anymore. I removed Tor Browser and when I tried to re-install it by running "torbrowser-launcher", I get the following error message:

```
Tor Browser Launcher
Von Micah Lee, lizensiert unter MIT
Version 0.3.3
https://github.com/micahflee/torbrowser-launcher
Erzeuge GnuPG Verzeichnis /root/.local/share/torbrowser/gnupg_homedir
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
Lade Tor Browser das erste mal herunter.
Herunterladen https://aus1.torproject.org/torbrowser/update_3/release/Linux_x86_64-gcc3/x/en-US
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/torbrowser-launcher", line 30, in <module>
    torbrowser_launcher.main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/torbrowser_launcher/__init__.py", line 98, in main
    gui.move(
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  move(self, QPoint): argument 1 has unexpected type 'float'
  move(self, int, int): argument 1 has unexpected type 'float'
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you try to update Tor to latest 0.3.5 version? try to run `./build_deb.sh` again.

Answer (score 22):

You can fix this by going into the `__init__.py` file and changing the lines (98) in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/torbrowser_launcher/`:

```
gui.move(
            (desktop.width() - window_size.width()) / 2,
            (desktop.height() - window_size.height()) / 2
        )
```

To:

```
gui.move(
            int((desktop.width() - window_size.width()) / 2),
            int((desktop.height() - window_size.height()) / 2)
        )
```

Another solution is posted on the official GitHub:
https://github.com/micahflee/torbrowser-launcher/issues/636 (which in general does the same)

Both solutions are valid. I assume it will be fixed in the next update.

**Explanation**
gui.move expects two integers, but can get two floats from the division. Therefore explicit casting to int is needed.

Comment: Another solution is posted on the official GitHub: https://github.com/micahflee/torbrowser-launcher/issues/636 (which in general does the same) This worked for me. Thanks Natan

Comment: Has a bug been filed?  Until a bug is filed the developers can't know a fix is required to be made.

Comment: @guiverc yes, there is an Ubuntu bug - waiting on Upstream to have a patch for inclusion

Comment: This is still an issue, seems like Ubuntu gets a stale torbrowser-launcher. I guess a solution is to get torbrowser from the producers directly, https://www.torproject.org/download/. You untar it (`tar xvf ./$packagename`), `cd` to the directory, then just run `./start-tor-browser.desktop`.

Answer (score 1):

I have Ubuntu 22.04 and Tor Browser not launching (Error 404...) Well.  But  if I go, in the  terminal, to

```
/Downloads/tor-browser-linux64-12.0.6_ALL/tor-browser
```

and type

```
  ./start-tor-browser.desktop --verbose
```

then Tor-Browser works, I do not why. Every time I start my system, I must do  the same in this way