# Ubuntu 22.04, internal error by starting the torbrowser

Tags: launcher, 22.04, versions, tor, tor-browser

despite of two solutions proposed
[Tor Browser not launching on Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404606/tor-browser-not-launching-on-ubuntu-22-04)
and
https://github.com/micahflee/torbrowser-launcher/issues/636
It doesn't work. I changed the **init**.py file according to the description.
In both cases, the error was persisting.

Just wondering if there is any update on this?
thanks a lot