# Can someone help me for the code for changing __init__.py file

Tags: command-line, tor

I am running Ubuntu 22.04 and can't get Tor browser to open - it opened in my previous Ubuntu 20.04.
I see the solution to the problem is given at this webaddress: [Tor Browser not launching on Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404606/tor-browser-not-launching-on-ubuntu-22-04) - BUT, I am not tech-savy (74 years old) and don't know exactly how to do the instructed:

> You can fix this by going into the `__init__.py` file and changing the lines (98) in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/torbrowser_launcher/`

Sadly, I do not know how to open and edit the `__init__.py` file

Is there some very kind soul who could let me know how I can do this (open the file to edit) and/or what I need to type into the terminal?

Comment: Whichever answer you end up following, note that files in `/usr/lib` are supposed to be exclusively managed by the owning package, so if there's _any_ update to the tor browser package, including say, just a rebuild due to a dependency update, that file will be replaced with the one from the package and your changes discarded.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using a newer, non-LTS Ubuntu to test, and Tor Browser works fine out of the box, so I can't guarantee that the other guy's solution works, but I can instruct you in a simpler, more detailed way.

Before trying this solution though, please type `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` in Terminal and hit enter.

If it asks you if you want to install the updates, hit Y and Enter, then try starting Tor Browser again.
If there are no updates, try the solution below:

First, you need to open Terminal and copy-paste `sudo gnome-text-editor /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/torbrowser_launcher/__init__.py`

It is a protected file, so type in your password. You should see a Text Editor window.
Now, press Ctrl+I (big i) to search by line number. Search for 98.

Select and delete this part:

```
gui.move(
            (desktop.width() - window_size.width()) / 2,
            (desktop.height() - window_size.height()) / 2
        )
```

Now, paste this instead:

```
gui.move(
            int((desktop.width() - window_size.width()) / 2),
            int((desktop.height() - window_size.height()) / 2)
        )
```

Done! If my anwser helped you, please accept it with the check mark button. If the latter part helped, also upvote @Natan's answer you linked in your question.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed - I really appreciate the time and trouble you have gone to. I will do as you say tomorrow - bed-time for me now!

Comment: I have done as you asked but note that I do not have a "torbrowser_launcher" folder where you indicate. I do have a "Tor-Browser" folder under my Home directory. I do see a few "Tor-Launcher.txt" files scattered about the place when doing a search - e.g. /home/duncan/Tor-Browser/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/TorBrowser/Docs/Licenses/Tor-Launcher.txt. Can you suggest how I should proceed? Many thanks for your very kind help.

Comment: P.S.  When I search for " __init__py " in the "Tor-Browser" directory I get no return.

Comment: Make sure you copy-pasted the command (sudo gnome-text-editor /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/torbrowser_launcher/__init__.py) and it's exactly the same. If it still doesn't work, where did you download Tor Browser Launcher from? From APT?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As I said, there is no "torbrowser_launcher" folder in my .../pyton3/dist-packages/" directory. So, no, it does not open - the editor opens with a blank page.
My Tor Browser app came with the Ubuntu 22.04 LTS when I upgraded to it from Ubuntu 20.04 where the Tor Browser was working nicely.
As I said above, I do have a "Tor-Browser" folder under my Home directory. I do see a few "Tor-Launcher.txt" files scattered about the place when doing a search - e.g. /home/duncan/Tor-Browser/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/TorBrowser/Docs/Licenses/Tor-Launcher.txt.

Comment: I would like to add a screenshot of the window I get when trying to start Tor but do not know how to upload it here - I can't see any attachment thingy.  Essentially the window says: "If Tor is blocked in your location, trying a bridge may help. Connection assist can choose one for you using your location, or you can configure your connection manually instead."  But this does bot work.  I have downloaded Tor from their website and it default downloads to my Home folder. I edtract the download but do not know which of the many files to use to open this. Totally lost - sorry.

Comment: Upload the image to Imgur, and share the link here.

Comment: Many thanks - here is the link to the 4 relevant images I have uploaded to Imgur a few minutes ago 09h32-BST:
https://imgur.com/PQLCsPh

Comment: Here is a DropBox link if you are having trouble with the Imgur one:
/home/duncan/Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot from 2023-10-21 09-28-25.png
/home/duncan/Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot from 2023-10-21 09-27-59.png
/home/duncan/Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot from 2023-10-21 09-21-51.png
/home/duncan/Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot from 2023-10-21 09-12-15.png

Comment: Idk, it seems fine. Just select "Always connect automatically" (if you want it to automatically do what actually you downloaded it for), and hit Connect.
It looks like the bridge message is not showing up. I don't live in a country that blocks Tor, and I got that message when the Wi-Fi connection was poor.

Comment: Still can't get it to work. But, many, many thanks for your time and help. Really appreciate it.

Comment: I cannot proceed because there is no "torbrowser_launcher" folder.
I do have a "Tor-Browser" folder under my Home directory. 
I see a few "Tor-Launcher.txt" files scattered about the place when doing a search - e.g. /home/duncan/Tor-Browser/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/TorBrowser/Docs/Licenses/Tor-Launcher.txt
I would be most grateful if you could advise how to proceed - i.e. to get/make the "torbrowser_launcher" folder and contents.

Comment: At this point, just wait for Ubuntu 24.04 LTS and upgrade when it comes out (in April). Because the package works for me on 23.10, it should work on 24.04 too.
But still referring to the image, Tor seems to launch so what is the problem?

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot make the problem any clearer than I have outlined above.